# Allow explanation of flags no matter the flag reason

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, flags

Since [flags are going into the Low Quality Posts queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226092/lets-get-rid-of-the-10k-flag-queue), I see myself using the "other" option of flagging more and more.

#### The problem

Since those flags are in the Low Quality Posts, the reviews are no longer as thorough as when they were in the 10K queue. Previously, people clicked on the answer and read it in the context of the other answers, while now people (including me) only review the post on its own.

That means that valid "Not an answer" flags are now rejected and marked as invalid, while they are a valid in the context of the complete question + its answers.

#### The solution

It would be great if we can give a small *optional* explanation of the flag for each reason, just like we can do when editing a post. This allows you to give some contextual information about the flag and reduces the change of wrongly reviewed flags.

Answer (score 6):

The reason for the change in review style isn't that these flags aren't visible to 10k users anymore, it's that these flags mostly aren't being handled by moderators. They're feeding into the Low Quality Posts review queue, where the decision to delete or not is being made by a group of reviewers. Despite people complaining for years that moderators didn't review these thoroughly enough, it turns out that the community is even more strict about these than we were.

"Not an answer" flags shouldn't need any further explanation. These flags should be used for anything that is obviously not an answer and that doesn't require any additional context to determine this. If you need to read the entirety of the question to determine that this doesn't belong, or should be a comment on something else, we recommend that you use an "other" flag and explain exactly why this answer needs to be deleted or converted to a comment.

If you're going to have to type out an explanation for a flag anyway, why not use an "other" flag? For many of these cases, you're flagging something that's better off as a comment, and only moderators have the ability to convert answers to comments.

To date, people have felt safe in revealing sensitive information in "other" flags because they knew that only moderators would see this information. If we expand this so that reviewers can also see this text for classes of flags, we'll need to make sure to caution people that anything they put in there will be publicly visible.

In regards to the recent flags that you've had disputed, I actually agree with the reviewers who disputed these two cases:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4713873

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4702511

Both of those were indeed attempts to answer the question asked, and I see no reason that those answers should be deleted. One of them was removed by the poster after being downvoted, but it still was an answer even if you felt it was too opinionated. I think the review system worked well for those cases.

Comment: "One of them was removed by the poster after being downvoted, but it still was an answer even if you felt it was too opinionated." Sorry, but I don't get you here. The question was about a PHP problem with calculating dates. Do you say an answer saying "Use a framework, most of them have helpers for to calculate with dates" is a correct answer? Firstly, frameworks doesn't have those things (incorrect answer -> downvote) and secondly, it doesn't even solve the problem.

Comment: "If you're going to have to type out an explanation for a flag anyway, why not use an "other" flag?" I wrote this question thinking that I should use mod-only flags as less as possible. After reading your answer, I think that was a wrong assumption. Thank you for explaining it!

Comment: @WouterJ - I'm not saying it was a good answer, but it was a legitimate attempt to answer the question. It wasn't "I'm having the same problem", "I like turtles", or "I have another question". Downvotes were probably more appropriate, along with a comment explaining why it was a bad answer. You did that, and they retracted it themselves.

Comment: And at last, commenting on the "sensitive information" thing. I didn't want people to give access to the "other" reasons. I want to have the same little text box when I click on "Not an answer", so I can write a short description.